# Why does my LCD display random characters?

Tags: lcd

I've been struggling with my LCD for hours, and after solving more different issues than I can remember, I'm out of ideas for this one.

My LCD is showing random characters, see the picture below (the last character blinks, some characters change and over time there are slowly more and more characters). I'm starting to wonder if the LCD I chose has a driver compatible with the LiquidCrystal library, what do you think? If so what can I do to avoid buying another one?

[image]

Here is the code:

```c
// include the library code:
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

// initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins
//RS EN D4 D5 D6 D7
LiquidCrystal lcd(2, 3, 4, 5, A2, A3);
//RW to GND, VSS to GND, VCC to 5V, V0 to wiper of 5V-to-GND 10k potentiometer

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Starting");
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
}

void loop() {
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(millis() / 1000);
  Serial.println("Printing");
  delay(1000);
}
```

I'm using this [Arduino](http://hobbycomponents.com/boards/140-arduino-compatible-5v-pro-mini-?search_query=pro%20mini&results=53) and this [LCD](http://uk.farnell.com/midas/mc21605h6w-sptly/lcd-2x16-stn-led-b-l-blk-on-y/dp/2342641). Note that I'm using pins 10,11,12,13 for a SD (which works) and 6 7 8 for a MAX232 (which is disabled).

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you set the library to 4 pin mode? And have you tried sending some regular text, like "hello" instead of the output of a function

Comment: I'm not sure whether the LiquidCrystal library supports using the "analog pins" A2 A3 that way. Can you test your LCD using the standard pin configuration (obviously not using the SD or any other interfering devices). The LCD itself looks like a common HD44780 type, so pin configuration is more likely the cause than some exotic device driver.

Comment: The LiquidCrystal library includes known-good example code, that's part of what Arduino is for. Go ahead and use that as a diagnostic to check the LCD works, before attempting the non-standard connection.

Comment: Thanks. The above code is an example on the official website, I've just added the delay() so it should work... I've checked and A2 and A3 are sending digital signals just like the other pins so it looks fine. Passerby, isn't it sufficient to call the constructor with 6 arguments to select 4 pin mode?

Comment: A lot of people having this issue had EMC issues - The 5V is supplied by a boost converter from a battery but I've observed the supply rail and it's a solid 5V...

Comment: Have you made sure you don't have any floating input pins?

Comment: The pins not labelled on the picture are left unconnected - should I ground them? All examples I've seen left them unconnected

Comment: Stupid question but the picture looks like you just pushed the wires in the holes. You did solder them, didn't you?

Comment: `Please don't migrate this post to Arduino SE for now` - too late!

Comment: check 2 and 3 :) again your soldiering is bad, well from what I know if there is "?" this sign you must check your connections

Comment: The connections are through hole, it doesn't matter which layer I solder them on, and they are soldered on the bottom. I've checked and the top pads are connected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be because "millis()/1000" generates a "number", and not the "string" (or "char"). Try to add ",DEC" in your lcd.print(), something like "millis()/1000,DEC" to convert it to "decimal". Generally, it depends on the library, how they implement this function.

Good luck,

Mike

Comment: You and Passerby were right about this, I ruled it out because it was an official example but it is obvious that their example was wrong. I changed that to "ABC...Z" and then "123...90" and both worked flawlessly. Thanks!